# Can you have multiple Excel worksheets for one SharePoint List?

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, excel

I know you can create a table in Excel and export that into SharePoint as a list. I want to know if you are capable of having two or more Excel files updating a single SharePoint list.

We want two different people to have the ability to update their own local Excel worksheet without getting it overwritten by the SP list. That way they each get to have an Excel worksheet with their own items and the SharePoint list gets all of the items. (They are both identical tables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not available as OOTB. but you can develop custom solutions as below

1. develop office add-on's which can interact with SharePoint and merge from two excel sources in to single list.
2. create two lists and the develop ribbon action with a custom layouts page say "export" in which the list data will be updated to the final target based on list contenxt.

Comment: I had the feeling that there was no simple way to do this. That's ok, it's not crucial enough to get too complicated with it.

Answer (score 1):

Their no OOTB way to handle these kind of situation.

One workaround i am thinking,If both files are identical then upload both files in SharePoint library. After that you can use PowerQuery to Consolidate both files and then create the list on the basis of new file. [Consolidate Multiple Excel Files in SharePoint using PowerQuery](http://exceleratorbi.com.au/consolidate-multiple-excel-files-in-sharepoint-using-powerquery/)

Another method, create a Custom timer job which reads the data from excel using [openXML](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1fda82c4-a1ab-420a-86ad-682a1d6d33cb/openxml-read-excel-file) and add into the list.

Answer (score 1):

This works well if you start the SharePoint-Excel sync from SharePoint side, not from Excel side. For this, you will need a third party tool.

I suggest having a look at [SharePoint List Synchronizer](http://www.synchronizer-for-excel-and-sharepoint.com) (disclaimer: I work for SoftFluent, the company behind this tool).

On top of what Microsoft tool offers, it lets you start from SharePoint. So you can read and modify your existing SharePoint lists from Excel. Any version of Excel, any version of SharePoint. As many users as you want can sync, according to their rights.

Again, files have to be saved as XLS (not XLSX) and you can't change the list structure from Excel. Worth noting that there is no server side setup. It's client only.

Answer (score 0):

why not create one list in SharePoint and create separate views for each user, that only shows their entries, you can then have another all items view for maintenance. The list will automatically be updated with both users new and updated items.